# Redirect nginx root dir to other url?

Tags: nginx, redirect, subdomain

i server static file with nginx. what i want to do it, that when someone browses to

```
http://foo.bar.com/
```

he gets redirected to

```
http://bar.com
```

but when i access the static file itself, it should serve that file, like:

```
http://foo.bar.com/blog/main.css
```

any advice?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need 2 server blocks, one for foo.bar and one for bar.

In the foo.bar server block you then specify a couple of locations.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ http://bar.com
}

location ~ ^/blog/.+\.(jpg|css|png)$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ http://bar.com
}
```

Nginx locations work by specificity so the regex location will be used before the location / if the URI matches, there we check if the file exist, and if it does serve it, otherwise we'll redirect any way.

I highly recommend you go read the wiki as all of this is specified there and it should help you understand this thoroughly.